# Order completeness property

Tags: real-analysis

What is the reason to call lub axiom in real numbers as order completeness property of real numbers?

I mean is there any intuition to call it like that.

Comment: The typical axioms of an ordered can lead to fields like $\mathbb{Q} $ where a strange scenario happens : a partition into two sets based on order generates no boundary or division point. And we may say that the ordering is not complete. When this deficiency is removed via we get a complete ordered field.

Comment: Suppose that in this world there are only rational numbers so we think that all real nos. are rational nos. Then a question arises: What is the least maximum value of $x$ which satisfies $x^2\lt 2$?There is no. such real no. (which by our assumption are rational nos only!) so we are left with some gaps of numbers that need to occupied by non-rational numbers! That's how we introduce irrational nos. Now we can find a "lowest bound" for every bounded subset of real nos. Hence, completeness i.e. no gaps!

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that $\operatorname{lub}$ axiom and completeness axiom (every Cauchy sequence converges) in $\Bbb{R}$ are equivalent. I guess that is the intuition to call it that.

Answer (score 0):

l.u.b axiom is also called Dedekind completeness. In my opinion, it is called so because it states that the real line is complete, i.e has no "holes".

An example that jumps to mind is how this property allows to show the intermediate value theorem :

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on the interval $[a, b]$, suppose $f(a) < c < f(b)$ for some $c$, then there is $x \in [a, b]$ such that $f(x) = c$.

Proof :
Define $B := \{x \in [a, b] \ \big| f(x) < c\}$.

$B$ has an upper bound (namely $b$), hence it has a least upper bound $x :=\sup(B)$, i.e $x$ is the minimum of the (non-empty) set $U := \{x \in [a, b] \ \big| f(x) \geqslant c\}$.

We claim that $f(x) = c$ :
Assume otherwise for contradiction. Then by continuity of $f$, there exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $y$ with $|x - y| < \epsilon$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \delta$ and hence $f(y) > c$. Now take $x - \epsilon < y_0 < x$, we get $y_0 \in U$ but $y_0 < x$, a contradiction since $x$ is the minimum of $U$. qed